# Need to convert piece of PHP code to C#

Tags: c#, php

I need to convert two PhP functions (sfGetCategoryAllTree and sfSideTree) to C#. I'm not used to PhP at all. I will show you the functions and what I did by now.

```
/**
 * Retrieves user data given a user id or user object.
 *
 * @param string $output Optional, default is Object. Either OBJECT, ARRAY_A, or ARRAY_N.
 * @return Category|null Category on success or null on failure
 */
function sfGetCategoryAllTree($output = OBJECT,$id='') {

    global $sfdb, $table_category, $table_category_lang;

    $categories = $sfdb->run("SELECT * FROM $table_category c"'
        ORDER BY position ASC", '', true)
            ->fetchAll($output);

    $all_categories = array();
    $all_relation = array();
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($categories as $c) {

        $all_categories[$c['id']] = $c;
        if ($c['parent_id'] == null) {
            $tree[] = $c;
            $all_relation[0][] = $c['id'];
        } else {
            $all_relation[$c['parent_id']][] = $c['id'];
        }
    }

    if (isset($all_relation[0])) {
        $tree = sfSideTree($all_relation[0], $all_categories, $all_relation);
    }
    return ($tree) ? $tree : array();
}

/**
 * Helps create the tree
 *
 * @param array $branch
 * @param array $categories
 * @param array $relation
 * @return array
 */
function sfSideTree($branch, $categories, $relation) {
    $tree = array();
    if (!empty($branch)) {
        foreach ($branch as $b) {
            $aux = $categories[$b];
            if (isset($relation[$b]) && is_array($relation[$b])) {
                $aux['categories'] = sfSideTree($relation[$b], $categories, $relation);
            } else {
                $aux['categories'] = array();
            }
            $tree[] = $aux;
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

Here what I did so far:

```
public void sfSideTree(int[] branch, Category[] categories, int[] relation)
        {
            Category[] tree = new Category[10];

            foreach (var b in branch)
            {
                var aux = categories[b];
                if (relation[b] != null)
                {
                    aux[]....
                }
            }
        }

        public void sfGetCategoryAllTree()
        {
            var categories = this.Query().Select().ToList();

            /*
            $all_categories = array();
            $all_relation = array();
            $tree = array();
            */
            //IList<Category> all_categories = new List<Category>();
            //IList<Category> all_relation = new List<Category>();
            //IList<Category> tree = new List<Category>();
            Category[] all_categories = new Category[10];
            int[] all_relation = new int[10];
            Category[] tree = new Category[10];


            foreach (var c in categories)
            {
                //$all_categories[$c['id']] = $c;
                all_categories[c.Id] = c;
                //all_categories.Add(new Category() { Id = item.Id });
                if (c.ParentId == 0)
                {
                    tree[??] = c; //???
                    all_relation[0] = c.Id;
                    /*

                    $tree[] = $c;
                    $all_relation[0][] = $c['id'];*/
                }
                else
                {
                    all_relation[c.ParentId] = c.Id;
                    //$all_relation[$c['parent_id']][] = $c['id'];
                }
            }

            if (all_relation != null)
            {
                sfSideTree(all_relation[0], all_categories, all_relation);
            }

                return tree;
            /*return ($tree) ? $tree: array();*/
        }
```

PhP arrays make life harder to translate. Does someone can help me?

David

### Edit

To answer to OwlSolo here the structure of Category class

```
public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming from your comment on my last answer, this is how I would implement this in C#:

```
public void makeTree()
{
    //Make a Dictionary with the ID als key
    Dictionary<int, Category> categories = this.Query().Select().ToDictionary(a => a.ID, a => a);

    foreach (Category c in categories)
    {
        if (c.ParentID != 0)
        {
            if (categories[c.ParentID].children == null)
            {
                categories[c.ParentID].children = new List<Category>();
            }
            categories[c.ParentID].children.add(c);         
        }//ParentID == 0 means its a root element
    }
}
```

This simply creates a tree structure from you query. If you need to expand a Category just access its list of children. Unless I'm overlooking something, this is what you really want to do here. There is no need to keep separate lists or another cluttery method for traversing the tree.

If you want to list all root Categories just go:

```
public List<Category> getRootNodes()
{
   List<Category> rootNodes = new List<Category>();
   foreach (Category c in categories)
   {
       if (c.ParentID == 0) rootNodes.Add(c);
   }
   return rootNodes;
}
```

**EDIT** Just realized that last function is pretty uneccessary as you can do it with linq much more easily

```
rootNodes = catergories.Where(x => x.ParentID == 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP arrays are not really 100% compatible to C# types, but you can get around that by using a lot of Dictionary for instance, as PHP lets you address field types by both int or string equivalents. This is certainly not the best practice, but so far is it rather unclear what data youre actually storing. 
I gave it a shot, but it **probably wont work right out of the box**. Depending on what data it actually is you have, some adjustments might be needed.

**EDIT:** In order for this to become a tree, your Category class also need a way to reference its children - in PHP this is accomplished by the ["categories"] field.

```
class Category
{
    [...]
    IList<Category> children;
}


//For instance as global arrays...
int[] all_categories;
int[] all_relation;



List<Category>  sfGetCategoryAllTree(output, id)
{   
    List<Category> tree;
    //$categories = $sfdb->run("SELECT * FROM $table_category c"'
    //    ORDER BY position ASC", '', true)
    //        ->fetchAll($output);  
    List<Category> categories = this.Query().Select().ToList();// Assuming this is aquivalent to the above selection statement...

    foreach (Category c in categories)
    {       
        all_categories[c.Id]  
        if (c.ParentId != 0) // The is no NULL for int, you might want to use the nullable type "int?" or an additional bool isRoot
        {
            if (tree == null) tree = new List<Category>();
            tree.Add(c);
            all_relation[0] = c.Id; 
        }else
        {
            all_relation[c.ParentId] = c.Id;
        }
    }   
    if (all_relation[0] != 0)
    {
        tree = sfSideTree(all_relation[0], all_categories, all_relation);
    }

    return tree;//returns the tree, or NULL 
}

List<Category> sfSideTree (int[] branch, Dictionary<int, Category> categories, int[] relation)
{
    List<Category> tree = new List<Category>();
    if (branch != null)
    {
        foreach (var b in branch)
        {
            if (relation[b] != null)
            {

                categories[b].categories = sdSideTree(relation[b], categories, relation)                        
            } else
            {
                categories[b].categories = new List<Category>();
            }
            tree = aux;
        }
    }
    return tree;
}
```

Comment: I added the model class in an Edit section :)

Comment: Alright, I gave a quick look, it looks nice. I will test it tomorrow. The only thing I can see by now is you're giving an int[] all_categories as second parameter for sfSideTree when the function is expecting a Dictionary<int, Category>.

Comment: As it just lists all the categories in total and the relations point to the IDs as int, I guess you could refactor this completely. I don'T really see a need to keep these separate lists, as you could get them by traversing the tree...But in the sense of just "converting" the code I would make all_categories a Dictionary<int, Category>

Comment: Alright, I have a last question. We have an array of int for all_relation variable, but it doesn't work with sfSideTree(all_relation[0]...) because the function expect another array of int instead of a simple int. The third parameter is good though. Do I'm right if I say we should also have a dictionary for that case?

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure how this is used and why this kind of structure was implemented in PHP. The way I see it, sfGetCategoryAllTree creates lists of relations between the categories, while sfSideTree traverses the relations and adds child elements to create a tree structure from the information in the lists. If you design it from scratch in C#, I would tackle this a whole other way - but without knowing the rest fo the code or what the actual purpose is here, i cannot add anythign further. But as an answer, from what I see, it needs to be a Dictionary so it can display the inheritance

Comment: Thank you very much for your help OwlSolo. To show the purpose of this, you can take a look at this module http://codecanyon.net/item/bootstrap-responsive-nestedsortable-jquery-based/full_screen_preview/8437924 You can add unlimited subcategories to a parent. The PhP code I showed you is the code that it's used when the page is loading to show the orders of categories and subcategories based on user latest selection.